# Cannot combine graphic objects while plotting two Smooth Histograms

Tags: plotting, graphics, histograms

I am trying to plot two smooth histograms, which I'm generating separately so I can chose their PlotStyle separately. When I run the code, it says I cannot combine the two graphic objects. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Sid

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormPage[{"k1" -> "Number", "n1" -> "Number", "n2" -> "Number", 
   "k2" -> "Number", "n3" -> "Number", "n4" -> "Number"},
  
  fig1 = SmoothHistogram[
     Table[Table[
       If[RandomReal[] > #k1, RandomChoice[{100, 90}], 
        RandomChoice[{80, 70, 60, 50, 40}]], #n1], #n2], 
     PlotStyle -> Red] &;
  fig2 = SmoothHistogram[
     Table[Table[
       If[RandomReal[] > #k2, RandomChoice[{100, 90}], 
        RandomChoice[{40, 30, 20, 10, 0}]], #n3], #n4] , 
     PlotStyle -> Gray] &;
  
  Show[{fig1, fig2}]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `FormPage` should be a single function of the inputs in the first argument.  So your code should be structured like:

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormPage[{"k1" -> "Number", "n1" -> "Number", "n2" -> "Number", 
   "k2" -> "Number", "n3" -> "Number", "n4" -> "Number"}, 
   (fig1 = SmoothHistogram[ <<stuff>> ];
    fig2 = SmoothHistogram[ <<stuff>> ];
    Show[{fig1, fig2}]) &
 ]
]
```

Note that there's only one `&`, after all the code in the second argument of `FormPage`.

I used `()` to make sure the `&` scoped all the code when constructing the function, but you could also use `Block` or `Module`:

```
Block[{fig1, fig2},
    fig1 = SmoothHistogram[ <<stuff>> ];
    fig2 = SmoothHistogram[ <<stuff>> ];
    Show[{fig1, fig2}]
]&
```

which might be nicer, especially for longer functions.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful.